# Speeding up the performance of write.table of complex data

Tags: r, optimization, file-io

I have a big number of data.frames and I want to write them out (in different locations). For the moment I use `write.table()`, but it would take me around 2.5 days to output all of these.

I have tried the `fwrite()` function from the `data.table` library, however it is not implemented for writing out complex numbers.

Do you have any suggestions how I could speed up the writing-out process?

Comment: maybe `saveRDS`?

Comment: https://rpubs.com/demydd/207377

Comment: Have you tried the `feather` package? That's what I use for saving large datasets to disk. It's wicked fast and is compatible with other programming languages.

Comment: the package `fst` is rather fast, but not stable yet, so it is not the best for long term storage. https://www.r-bloggers.com/fst-fast-serialization-of-r-data-frames/